# Add Wordpress User meta information in admin

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to add a custom field into my users section of the wordpress admin, I have a registration field that has an input for company, i can see the company value in the wp_usermeta table but need to get it in the users column in the admin, any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Try this [here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-custom-user-profile-fields)

Comment: Thankyou, looks useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add action and filter hooks for showing custom value in users table. Place the following into your theme's functions.php. Notice: 'PLACE COLUMN NAME HERE' and 'PLACE META KEY HERE':

```
function add_custom_column_name($columns) {
    $columns['columns_array_name'] = 'PLACE COLUMN NAME HERE:';
    return $columns;
}
function show_custom_column_values($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    if ( 'columns_array_name' == $column_name )
        return get_user_meta( $user_id, 'PLACE META KEY HERE', true );
    return $value;
}

add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'add_custom_column_name');
add_action('manage_users_custom_column', 'show_custom_column_values', 10, 3);
```